# When looping through an object's properties, how do I check if a key is optional?

Tags: typescript, reflection

Consider the following:

```js
interface TestObject { param: string, foo?: string }
const object: TestObject = { 
   param: "hello"
   foo?: "bar"
}
```

The above has an optional parameter but, say we didn't have an interface, and the object was [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

How would I determine if keys were optional by looping through the property of a given object? (See below)

```js
const takeAnObject = (object: unknown) => {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key: string) => {
      if(key === OPTIONAL){ 
         console.log(`${key} is an optional parameter`) 
      } else { 
         console.log(`${key} is a required parameter`) 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reflection in TypeScript; the type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when you compile to JavaScript.  Why do you need this? What's the underlying use case that makes you want such information at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. At runtime, there is no **type** information.
What you can do is create some kind of schema for your objects, and then validate them against that schema. One of the most popular packages for that is [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)